# Is it correct to say "I go here", when referring to attending a school?

Tags: grammar

I've often heard teens and grown ups saying "I go here" when referring to attending a school or an educational institution.  For some reason, I want to correct them and have them rephrase it as, "I attend here" or "I come here." Which is the right way of saying it?

Answer (score 8):

It is fine colloquially to say "I go here," meaning you attend school in the school which you currently happen to be standing in.

The usual way (in America) one asks the question is:

> Where do you go to school?

And the usual reply is:

> I go to [Insert school name].

That said, the only time you are likely to say "I go here" is if you are asked directly, "Do you go to this school?" This would probably be asked by someone, perhaps a teacher, who didn't think you belonged at that school and wanted to make sure you weren't up to some kind of mischief. Normally it would be obvious to your schoolmates where you attend school.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting that it seems to be a property of "go" meaning "attend" that it overrides the normal connotation that the goal is a place other than where the speaker is.